# Criteria for "Populist" Badge

Tags: support, badges

> Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

This is what is written in badge info which confused me a bit.

Do one have to earn $2x+10$ votes on a answer where the accepted answer has got $x$ votes?
Please Explain.

Comment: I think it means you have to get more than $2x$, and $x$ has to be more than $10$.

Comment: exploringnet, why did you add back the dollar signs in the title? They serve no purpose here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a given question, *once* there is someone with an answer that meets the following criteria:

- it is accepted
- it has 10 or more votes

the **other** answerers now have the opportunity to win the Populist badge, by having their answer voted to twice the score of the accepted answer, or more.

Comment: At least twice the score or strictly more than twice the score?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure it's "at least" (that is, exactly twice still wins it).

Comment: We can run an experiment on this page; someone else add an answer, and we just ask people to keep the votes exactly 20:10, then see if the badge is given (by waiting a day); then try to upvote to 21:10 and see; then 22:11 and then 23:11. One of these must work.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I have just upvoted [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/83968) from 53 t0 54 whereas the accepted answer has 27. My guess is that the badge is limited to once per question, but we'll see if N.S. gets another Populist badge (which I doubt). Note that I think the answer definitely deserves the upvote.

Comment: @robjohn: You should lock that thread so no one will screw up with the votes until tomorrow! :-P

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I have locked the answers, and left a note saying that if either of the authors want, I will remove the locks.

Comment: @robjohn: Oh, that was a joke. But sure. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: just remind me to unlock them tomorrow :-)

Comment: @robjohn: Perhaps unlock it already, http://math.stackexchange.com/badges/39/populist?userid=9176 I doubt the badge can be re-given to the same user on the same question.

Comment: @robjohn: On the other hand, I don't think any of the answerers on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268726/ got Populist badges. Try upvoting Alan's answer and we'll see what happens (it is also the case of 22:11, as long as my answer is not upvoted, feel free to lock it for a day or two...)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: good test case. I am sure I will hear something if I forget to unlock it ;-)

Comment: @robjohn: amWhy just received the Populist badge, so it's an immediate gold badge; but no one else did. So perhaps there is a one badge per thread limit. Either way we proved it has to be $+11$ on the accepted answer, or higher.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: that matches what the description says: *more* than $2\times$.

Answer (score 3):

Some experiments that me and robjohn ran in the comments to Zev's answer conclude the following:

1. The accepted answer has to have the score of **at least** 11 points.
2. Only the top voted answer can earn you the Populist badge, so if there are several answers which have twice, or more, points than the accepted only the top one gets the badge.

Open problems:

1. Do you have to have **more than twice**, or will **exactly** twice earn you the badge?
2. What happens if several of the answers are tied at the top score (including up/down equality)?
3. Why did they make a fifth Die Hard?
4. What happens if a Populist badge was already given to an answer, and then a new answer comes along and trumps the Populist-winning answer? Is the badge taken, or do the new answer get a badge at all?

Comment: 4. What if the accepted answer has at least 11, another answer has more than twice that and gets the Populist badge, and then a third answer comes along and gets more than the second answer (or even more than twice the second answer)? Does the third answer get a badge in that case? Does the second answer lose a badge when it gets passed by the third? And why did they make a first Die Hard?

Comment: @Gerry: Good question; the first Die Hard was great.

Comment: @hardmath: Considering that six months ago Willis retired from acting due to aphasia, that comment is in poor taste...

Answer (score 2):

> #### Populist
>
> - gold; awarded multiple times
> - Provide an answer that meets all of the following criteria ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6886)):
> - it is the highest scoring answer on the question ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6938)) or [tied for the highest score](https://web.archive.org/web/20191018064223/https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/37/populist)
> - it does *not* have the accepted checkmark
> - it has a score of 23 or more
> - it has at least one vote more than double the score of the accepted answer
> - the accepted answer has a score of 11 or more
> - it is not an answer *to your own question* ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119221))

The above excerpt is taken from [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for) thread of the Meta Stack Exchange.